# Can CKAN support Solr 7.0?

Tags: apache, solr, jetty, ubuntu-16.04, ckan

I am trying to install Solr 7.0 and CKAN 2.7.2 in Ubuntu 16.04. However, I got the following **errors**:

**From Solr admin website:**

> ckan: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load conf for core ckan: Can't load schema /var/solr/data/ckan/conf/schema.xml: Setting defaultSearchField in schema not supported since Solr 7

**From CKAN installation when initiating Database:**

> Solr responded with an error (HTTP 404): [Reason: Error 404 Not Found]

So I wonder whether CKAN could support the newest version of Solr. Currently, CKAN 2.7.2 can support Solr 4.6 with Jetty8.

Comment: Congratulations, you could well be the first to use CKAN in Solr 7. I encourage you to do/sponsor the necessary dev effort and create a pull request on CKAN so others can benefit. Happy to discuss - see https://github.com/ckan/ckan#contributing-to-ckan

Answer (score 7):

After some tinkering, and using this page about [Solr 6.5 with CKAN](https://github.com/ckan/ckan/wiki/Install-and-use-Solr-6.5-with-CKAN) as a starting point, I managed to use CKAN 2.8 with Solr 7.4 in Ubuntu 18.04:

1) in the CKAN .ini configuration file, **`solr_url` must include the core name**, otherwise CKAN calls to Solr fail (*SearchError: SOLR returned an error running query ... [Reason: Error 404 Not Found] ...*)

e.g. `solr_url = http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/ckan/` where `ckan` is the Solr core name

2) in the xml Solr schema, **replace**

```
<defaultSearchField>text</defaultSearchField>
<solrQueryParser defaultOperator="AND"/>
```

with

```
<df>text</df>
<solrQueryParser q.op="AND"/>
```

as those features have been deprecated ([1](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_0/major-changes-in-solr-7.html#other-deprecations-and-removals), [2](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_0/the-standard-query-parser.html#standard-query-parser-parameters))

Answer (score 2):

Please note that since Solr 6.0 the schema.xml is not required in solr instance.

The default `schema.xml` is changed to `managed-schema`, you can use schema.xml to override this file, and then delete the `managed-schema`.

From your error message, you maybe should update the `schema.xml` as some Fields are not supported in Solr 7.0.

Comment: To disable using the managed schema, you need to instruct Solr to use the old schema.xml configuration. In your `solrconfig.xml` add `<schemaFactory class="ClassicIndexSchemaFactory"/>` under the `<config>` section.