# What version of Solr is required for CKAN-2.8.3?

Tags: solr, version, ckan

I'm doing an installation of CKAN 2.8.3 on CentOS 7.

What version of Solr is required for CKAN-2.8.3?

I've read the post here:

https://github.com/ckan/ckan/wiki/How-to-install-CKAN-2.x-on-CentOS-7

which is for some 2.x older than 2.8.3.  In there they mention that Solr 1.4.1 is required.  I'm wondering if that has changed for a newer 2.x.  It would also be nice to know if this requirement is documented anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can use solr 6.5.1 or 6.6 versions following this [Install-and-use-Solr guide](https://github.com/ckan/ckan/wiki/Install-and-use-Solr-6.5-with-CKAN). 
Also, CKAN should work with solr version 7 but you will need to do minor changes to solr schema [for more info see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48533541/can-ckan-support-solr-7-0)